# How do I change the default share folder in dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

When I want to upload files to dropbox from external apps (share button) I always get directed to the same dropbox folder. Even if I delete it, it will come back from the dead next time I share with dropbox.

Is there a way to choose a different folder to share with dropbox when using third party apps?

Comment: You can customise using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync)

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem and it was very easy solving this. If you are in the "share" dialog just use the back button of your phone and you are back in the parent folder. Found the solution [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/From-Android-when-sharing-with-quot-Add-File-to-Dropbox-quot-can/td-p/207759). So I hope that also solves your problem!